# Can't Change A C++ Variable After Initializing

Tags: c++, linux

I am very new to C++ and am getting stuck with some very simple stuff. I am operating on ubuntu 14.04. I have seen several examples of code like the following. But I get only errors.

```
int x;
x = 12;

// output
error: ‘x’ does not name a type
```

I want to do simple and useful code but this has me stuck. Why can't I do

```
int z = 12;
z = 4;

// output
error: ‘z’ does not name a type
```

I have followed a fair number of C++ tutorials and succeeded in running the code. But now I find I can't simply change a variable. Makes it very tough to write code! Of course I did try to "type" the variables for the lines that resulted in this error.

```
int z = 12;
int z = 4;
// output
error: redefinition of ‘int z’
```

Damned if I do and if I don't. Anyone with any help??

EDIT: ok people, your killing me with the down votes. I am BRAND NEW to c++ and doing lot's of homework, before this post I found no relief. This is a catch 22: downed for ignorance and can't defeat ignorance without some help! BIG thank you for the comments and answers. NOW I GET IT.

Comment: Code goes in functions.

Comment: Many thanks chris. What a drag that was. Stop my new language learning dead. I put the code in a function and it works. Now it's onwards and up. =) cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, with really bad compiler options, this compiles in C (although it still needs a main function). Just another way C differs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your code in a function. Most likely the main function since you're still beginning the language try:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int x;
  x = 12;
  //enter what ever code is next
  return 0;

 }
```

Comment: I put the code in it's own function before "main" and also in main. Both work. Thanks Jecht.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this into a `main` function to get started. Try:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    x = 42;

    return 0; // success
}
```

Comment: Technically, the `int x;` line, and even `int z = 12;` is perfectly fine outside of a function. That's just the devil's advocate in me saying that tho'.

Comment: @Jongware I know, but lets not bother a beginner with that. For the OP it's not important right now and having something that actually compiles and can be executed is the most important step.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That would work. But the more general "in a function" is more generally right I understand. So I will accept another ans.

Comment: @RandySkretka: the issue Daniel and I are talking about is "function scope" versus "global scope". Do you happen to have previous knowledge on that from one of your other languages?

Comment: @RandySkretka Your choice, but `main` is a function - the one that is actually executed. Putting it into some other function won't execute the code unless you call that other function from the `main` function. (Granted, with those two statements you won't see any difference yet)

Comment: @Daniel: see my comment to Jecht. I put the function call in main.
AT:Jongware: yes, I understand scope. c++ is very challenging and new.

Comment: @Jongware Randy said he is new to c++. We don't want to cloud his learning with advanced concepts too early.